# Reading header response in angular post request

Tags: angular, spring, http

I have a method in an angular project that calls a backend entry point developped with Spring boot.

My method in angular is a basic authentication call :

```
authenticate(authRequest: AuthRequest) {
      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/users/login", authRequest, {responseType: 'text'} )

    .subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        console.log(res)
        // console.log(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
      },
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log("Done")
  });
}
```

I have also a similar call to a get request and this method :

```
dummy() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/users/test" , {observe: 'response', responseType: 'text'})
    .subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        alert(res);
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
      },
      error: (err) => console.log(err),
      complete: () => console.log("Done")
    });
}
```

In the back end i implemented a AuthenticationFilter class that contains the following method:

```
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // String userName = ((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    String userName = ((UserPrincipalManager) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    String organization = ((UserPrincipalManager) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUserEntity().getClientName();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(
            SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            SecurityConstants.HMAC_SHA_256);

    ClaimsDetails details = getClaimsFromUser((UserPrincipalManager) authResult.getPrincipal());

    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setId(((UserPrincipalManager) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUserId())
            .setSubject(userName)
            .setIssuer(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
            .setAudience(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
            .claim("user-details", details)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(secretKeySpec)
            .compact();

    UserService userService = (UserService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
    UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);

    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.USER_ID, userDto.getUserId());

}
```

I can't access response header. If i add the following line in my filter:

```
    response.getWriter().write("Authentication successful");
```

My respose is a string and i retrieve it. My issue is that my headers are empty and not retrieved. I do suppose my problem is in my query request in angular.
The call to the backend works in postman.

[image]

In the debugger:

[image]

I also checked if i received or not the data in my web browser, I noticed that I retrieved the data when consulting the network tab in chrome.

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No i didn't have error. I thought i gave you an answer. I fixed my issue (see answer below).  It was coming from Springboot and my cors & security configuration

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what was the problem and how to solve it. Ok, it was a backend issue: I have a bean in my web security that aims to solve cors problems. Here is my final version of the code:

```
@Bean
// cors configuration source
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    // corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));

    corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader("userId");
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays
             .asList("Authorization", "userId", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}
```

I simply added the following lines:

```
corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader("userId");
//corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays
     .asList("Authorization", "userId", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
```

If i understand well, the exposed headers must be defined and set.
it solves my problem even if i don't really get why setAllowedHeader didn't solve it alone and why adding Authorization to exposedHeaders make now visiable Cache-Control or content type for example.